# Define a constructor for a class whose members exist according to the template base classes

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'm working on a class to identify an image inside a texture, something like this:

```c++
using level_t = ...
using layer_t = ...
using face_t = ...

template <bool>
struct levels {};

template <>
struct levels<true> {
    level_t level = level_t{0};
};

template <bool>
struct layers {};

template <>
struct layers<true> {
    layer_t layer = layer_t{0};
};

template <bool>
struct faces {};

template <>
struct faces<true> {
    face_t face = face_t{0};
};

template <bool HasLevels, bool HasLayers, bool HasFaces>
struct index : levels<HasLevels>, layers<HasLayers>, faces<HasFaces> {};
```

Where `level_t`, `layer_t` and `face_t` are a sort of "strong typedef" for an int (basically different types that look like an int but without the implicit conversions).

Now I can use my type like so:

```c++
using Index1 = index<true, true, false>;
void f(Index1);

Index1 v;
v.level = level_t{1};
v.layer = layer_t[1};
f(v);
```

But to make the life easier for my users I want to allow this code:

```c++
f({level_t{1}, layer_t{1}};
```

The aggregate initialization is out due the base classes, so I need to write a constructor on my own; what is the best/smartest way to write a constructor that supports all the argument combinations (but not the reorder)?

Comment: Is there a reason that you have to use multiple inheritance instead of aggregation?

Comment: What do you mean by `all the argument combinations (but not the reorder)`? Are you referring to any template argument value without reordering constructor's parameters?

Comment: @zneak in this case yes,according to how the `index` type is "configured" some attributes must disappear and try to use them must result in a compile error

Comment: @PawełStankowski given `index<true, false, true>` I want a constructor that accepts (level_t, face_t) but not (face_t, level_t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are a bit terrible if you pass the wrong types or number of arguments, so I'm not sure this is worth it, ***but***…

One thing needed is a way to filter and randomly-access a pack of types; realistically I would use [Brigand](https://github.com/edouarda/brigand) or [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/libs/hana/) for this, but I'll stick with `std::tuple<>` here to keep this standard:

```
namespace detail {
    template<template<bool> class Holder, bool B>
    std::integral_constant<bool, B> holder_value_(Holder<B>);

    template<typename HolderT>
    constexpr decltype(detail::holder_value_(std::declval<HolderT>())) holder_value() {
        return {};
    }

    template<typename UnfilteredT, typename FilteredT>
    struct filter_holders;

    template<typename UnfilteredT, typename FilteredT = std::tuple<>>
    using filter_holders_t = typename filter_holders<UnfilteredT, FilteredT>::type;

    template<typename... Fs>
    struct filter_holders<std::tuple<>, std::tuple<Fs...>> {
        using type = std::tuple<Fs...>;
    };

    template<typename U, typename... Us, typename... Fs>
    struct filter_holders<std::tuple<U, Us...>, std::tuple<Fs...>> : filter_holders<
        std::tuple<Us...>,
        std::conditional_t<holder_value<U>(), std::tuple<Fs..., U>, std::tuple<Fs...>>
    > { };
}
```

Another thing needed is a way to find what intlike-type a 'holder'-type is wrapping (e.g. that `levels<true>` wraps a `level_t`, etc.). This can be done non-intrusively, but here I'll assume an internal `value_type` typedef.

With those in place it's fairly straightforward – we get a pack of base types for which the template argument is `true` and write a constructor whose initializers are just an expansion of that pack:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename... HolderTs>
    std::tuple<typename HolderTs::value_type...> value_types_(std::tuple<HolderTs...>);

    template<typename HoldersT>
    using value_types_t = decltype(detail::value_types_(std::declval<HoldersT>()));
}

template<bool HasLevels, bool HasLayers, bool HasFaces>
struct index : levels<HasLevels>, layers<HasLayers>, faces<HasFaces> {
private:
    using bases_t = std::tuple<levels<HasLevels>, layers<HasLayers>, faces<HasFaces>>;
    using true_bases_t = detail::filter_holders_t<bases_t>;
    using arg_types_t = detail::value_types_t<true_bases_t>;

    template<std::size_t... Is, typename... ArgTs>
    index(std::index_sequence<Is...>, ArgTs&&... args)
    : std::tuple_element_t<Is, true_bases_t>{std::forward<ArgTs>(args)}... { }

public:
    index() = default;

    template<
        typename... ArgTs,
        std::size_t S = sizeof...(ArgTs),
        typename = std::enable_if_t<
            S && std::is_same<std::tuple<std::decay_t<ArgTs>...>, arg_types_t>{}
        >
    >
    index(ArgTs&&... args)
    : index{std::make_index_sequence<S>{}, std::forward<ArgTs>(args)...} { }
};
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f20980d2297b61b)**</kbd>

**EDIT:** Updated with stricter implementation that doesn't allow convertible-but-not-same argument types, and doesn't incorrectly interfere with copy/move-construction.

Comment: I'm already using Boost.Hana, so I'm changing your code to use it. Never thought it was possible to use a meta function (std::tuple_element_t) as a base class initializer, wow :)

Comment: @dvd : Yea, the base-initializer just needs to name the base somehow, but not necessarily directly; so `decltype`, simple typedefs, traits/metafunctions, etc. are all viable options. I'm glad you're already using Hana; IMO it will easily lead to the cleanest implementation here, it's just a hard library to sell in the context of a SO answer without having a 3-page long answer. ;-]

Comment: @dvd : (I'm not sure if question-authors get notifications for answer edits...) Updated with an important fix for `index`'s copy/move-constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo code which allowed the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A {
  A() = default;
  A(const A &) {
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct B {
  B() = default;
  B(const B &) {
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct C {
  C() = default;
  C(const C &) {
    std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <class... Base>
struct Hyper : public Base... {
  template <class... Args>
  Hyper(Args&&... args) : Base(std::forward<Args>(args))... {}
};

template <class... Base>
auto factory(Base&&... args) {
  return Hyper<std::decay_t<Base>...>(std::forward<Base>(args)...);
}

int main() {
  auto obj = factory(A{}, B{}, C{});
  return 0;
}
```

All base classes of Hyper are copy/move constructed.

Some `static_assert` can be added to `factory` to prevent it from generating any freaky class.

As the comment says, this is not a good idea. If you do it right, everything will be fine, but if you do it wrong, even a small mistake, template + multi-inheritance can be your nightmare. (You may end up with 100000 lines of compiler error message.)

Comment: To prevent funky classes, you can define a type trait `template<typename T> using is_valid_base = std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, A>::value || std::is_same<T, B>::value || std::is_same<T, C>::value>;`